# Gson get complex array values

Tags: java, rest, gson, crud

in the last hours I was working with REST and Gson. But now I stuck.

I have this code:

```
public class Main {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main example = new Main();
        String response = example.run("http://localhost/crud/api.php/contacts/");
        System.out.println(response);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Contact fetchedContacts = gson.fromJson(response, Contact.class);

        System.out.println( fetchedContacts.toString() );

    }
}
```

And my localhost apache server return me this JSON

```
{
    "contacts":
    {
        "columns":
        [
            "id",
            "name",
            "email",
            "tel"
        ],
        "records":
        [
            [
                1,
                "Simon",
                "s@imon.de",
                "911"
            ],
            [
                2,
                "Ganter",
                "gan@t.er",
                "911"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

But the object is `null`. I now this code doesn't work. But how to fix it?
What are the next steps to take? I also have a class for my contacs:

```
public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String tel;

    public Contact(String name, String email, String tel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.tel = tel;
    }
```

Comment: Your Apache server needs fixed if that's your Gson model you want...

Comment: Won't you need the id property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson wants this

```
{"name":"",  "email":"",  "tel":""}
```

Anything else / extra will be null.

Seems like you need to learn some more PHP / MySQL or entirely switch to a web framework you are more comfortable with.

Sidenote: Retrofit would be a useful Java library once you get the API corrected

Comment: I was using the [crud-php-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api), which other framework can you recommend me?

Comment: I would probably not use a library at all, or just read its documentation... https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/blob/master/README.md#list--transform

Comment: wow, thank you. That was the point! And I will have a look ate Retrofit!